# Port remains blocked after opening

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

I have a TP-Link WR841ND Router. To test a server, I've had to open port 69.

When the router is connected to my internet at home, and I do the router's routine of opening a port (I know how, have done many times before), I can successfully accept incoming connections, and other people can connect to me. When I try the **exact** same procedure with the **exact** same router at a friend's house, incoming connections are blocked. Even the server-device used was the same.

During all this, no Windows firewall / virus scanner (or any other software-security) was active.

The only differences I can note is that my friend also has interactive-TV attached to his modem, and that I am using a PPPoE connection in order to connect to my ISP, whereas my friend uses a 'dynamic IP' setting. We are both using the same ISP. Could it be something in the modem that is blocking incoming connections? I'm completely baffled--what am I missing?

I have tried:

- Open the port as virtual-server linked to my static LAN IP. With my home internet it worked, at my friend's house it didn't.
- Disabled the router's firewall.
- Simple port opener (the software). Made no difference.
- Rebooting the router a million times in between setting changes, and trying again.
- Enabling DMZ on my friend's router--made no difference either.

Comment: "We are both using the same ISP." As mentioned in the post, I had already tried DMZ. ( @Nifle , please remove the 'duplicate of' for this question. This clearly is not a duplicate, and I'm afraid that if people think it is a duplicate, they will not answer it. Thank you.)

Comment: Just because you are using the same ISP does not mean that there is must be no firewall between you and your friend.

Comment: Have you contacted your ISP to find out if they have port blocking enabled?  Since you are making a PPPoE connection the rules for you connection are going to be different.